# Fundamental Frequencies of different instruments

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, frequency-domain, fundamental-frequency

I'm trying to study what differentiates different instruments in terms of frequencies, timbre, etc.
By studying a few different samples of notes, I've come to the conclusion that for flutes the fundamental frequency is also the dominant one, and for piano that's not true. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: That depends a lot on the specific instrument and the way it's played (and recorded). Where do you want to go with this? This has been studied in great detail and there are tons of literature and multiple text books available. For example https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/File:Instrument_spectra_(A4-440Hz).png

Comment: @Hilmar I'm trying to find a way to classify instruments using their timbre, fundamental & dominant frequencies, etc. I'm trying to find a pattern in the frequencies of flutes and pianos, so far I have yet to find a distinct pattern in regards to their dominant frequencies and harmonics.

Comment: There have been entire books written on the topic (and it's a complicated one). Is there anything new or different you are trying to do ?

Comment: @Hilmar I don't know if it's necessarily new... I want to write a code that will classify instruments, so I want to understand first the mathematical difference between instruments, however, what I found on the internet does not correlate with my own findings and so I'm a bit at a crossroad.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this conclusion correct?

It feels too general. Musical instruments are fairly complicated and the spectrum is dependent on a lot of different things: what note you play, how the note is played and intonated, how the recording is done, etc.

For example, the "dominance" of the fundamental for a flute depends on how hard you blow. The harder you hit it, the more harmonics you get. See for example: http://www.altoflute.co.uk/03-dynamics/spectral-analysis.html.

For something like an electrical guitar it would depend a lot the location of the pick up (neck vs bridge), how the string is getting excited (pick, finger tip, thumb strumming, palm muting, etc.), tone controls and volume setting, etc.